# Generate Rust ffi bindings to C++ library

Tags: c++, rust, ffi

I'm trying to use the [cxx crate](https://docs.rs/cxx/0.5.1/cxx/) to generate rust bindings for [helios_dac](https://github.com/Grix/helios_dac). The DAC code is pretty much just a header file (HeliosDAC.h) and an implementation (HeliosDAC.cpp). It also depends on libusb.h but we'll burn that bridge when we get to it.

Here is my buiild script:

```
//build.h

fn main() {
    cxx_build::bridge("src/lib.rs")
        .cpp(true)
        .file("src/HeliosDac.cpp")
        .flag_if_supported("-std=c++14")
        .flag_if_supported("-fPIC")
        .compile("helios-bridge");

    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/lib.rs");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/HeliosDac.cpp");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/HeliosDac.h");
}
```

And here is my bridge code:

```
//lib.rs

#[cxx::bridge]
mod ffi {
    extern "C" {
        include!("helios/src/HeliosDac.h");

        type HeliosDac;
        // Functions implemented in C++.
        fn HeliosDac() -> UniquePtr<HeliosDac>;
        fn OpenDevices() -> i32;
        fn CloseDevices() -> i32;
        //fn WriteFrame(devNum: u32, pps: u32, flags: u8)
    }

    extern "Rust" {
    }
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        assert_eq!(2 + 2, 4);
        let ndevs = ffi::OpenDevices();
        println!("{}", ndevs);
    }
}
```

The code is organized as follows.

```
helios/
    build.rs
    src/
        HeliosDac.cpp
        HeliosDAC.h
        libusb.h
        lib.rs
```

When I run `cargo build` the compiler tries its best to help me out but I can't understand. For every "C" function I implement it gives a warning about the function name not being in scope:

```
cargo:warning=   int32_t (*CloseDevices$)() = CloseDevices;
cargo:warning=                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And it even gives me a suggestion:

```
note: suggested alternative: ‘CloseDevices$’
```

So it can see a function name but there's an extra ampersand on the end? **Can someone explain to a newb what's going on here?**

Comment: C++ names and functions work quite a bit differently than C. Look up "name mangling" for one. Try running bindgen on the header file.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The cxx crate is supposed to handle mangling by itself. However it looks like those are methods on the C++ side, but the binding declares them as free functions.